# Getting the input's text when no selection is made

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, combobox

I've been stuck on trying to get around this code for hours.
I've used a similar code to [jqueryui combobox](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox)

Users want to be able to choose from a list, or type in their own options if none in the list is shown.

The thing that is giving me trouble, is when a value is typed in the input, it returns null for selection, since it don't match with anything. So on submit, the value returned is NULL.

Is there a way to pullup the value of the input, rather than the select value?

Thank you.

Comment: Why not add a value of "other" to the drop down, and use some jquery to show the input when other is selected; then to handle the inputs if(selection=="other"){get value of input text}

Comment: Yes, this is my solution as of yet. When others is selected, unhide a text box and make them specify. Still I think its defeating the purpose of having a combo textbox widget. Thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

I would check for a value of your combobox first. If no value is found (or null) check for a value in the text input. If no value is found there (both have null values) then you could throw an error that nothing was selected.

Something like this:

```
var value;
if ( $('combobox').val() )
{
     value = $('combobox').val());
}
else
{
    if ($('textbox').val())
    {
       value = $('textbox').val();
    }
    else
    {
       alert('Hey, you gotta have a value!');
    }
}
```